# playerprefs stopped my value from being updated after some time. It was updating before using playerpref. C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game, there's a value which updates after some time. If value changes during game, it will update after some time. But when I used playerprefs, value stopped updating after dedicated time. If value changes during game, it keeps storing that value which means playerprefs is working, but value doesn't update.

Variable declaration

```
    public Text CovidBudget;
    public int Covid_Budget;

    public Text TimerText_budget;
    public float timeValue_budget = 30;
```

Function that changes value of `Covid_Budget`

```
    public void covid_budget()
    {
        Covid_Budget = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("C_B", (int)(0.01 * economy_worth));
        CovidBudget.text = Covid_Budget.ToString();
     }
```

Function that displays time after which value should update.

```
public void DisplayTime_budget(float timeToDisplay_b)
    {
        if (timeToDisplay_b < 0)
        {
            timeToDisplay_b = 0;
        }
        else if (timeToDisplay_b > 0)
        {
            timeToDisplay_b += 1;
        }
        float minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeToDisplay_b / 60);
        float seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeToDisplay_b % 60);

        TimerText_budget.text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", minutes, seconds);
    }
```

Code that runs time and updates the value of `Covid_Budget`

```
void Update()
{
if (timeValue_budget > 0)

            {
                timeValue_budget -= PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("bud_time", Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else
            {
                timeValue_budget = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("bud_time", 30);
                covid_budget();
                
            }

            DisplayTime_budget(timeValue_budget);
}
```

Comment: First of all ... Unity message methods (`Start`, `Update`, etc) are case-sensitive and have to be named exactly like Unity expects - UpperCase! Otherwise they are just **never called**. And then why do you have a nested method `public void covid_budget` within the `start` (which should be `Start`) method?

Comment: I wrote that manually here, my bad. Code is all right in my editor. I have corrected the question.

Comment: Ok then what do you expect to hapen here exactly? Currently you are always only ever reading values from the PlayerPrefs via the key "bud_time" (and "C_B") ... if this key does not exist it will use the fallback values `Time.deltaTime` or `30` (and `(int)(0.01 * economy_worth)`) ... is anything ever setting these (`PlayerPrefs.SetFloat`) ? And what if now e.g. `bud_time` has a value of lets say `30` => you reduce `timeValue_budget` until it reaches `0` and then again set it to `30` => it reduces to `0` within **one single frame** => you reset it to `30` etc => flicker between two values

Comment: It sounds to me that especially for the reducing you just want to stick to `Time.deltaTime` without reading any value from the PlayerPrefs there